# react native upgrade from version 0.61.1 to the latest stable version in the 70 series

Tags: react-native

I'm currently working on a React Native project and planning to upgrade from version 0.61.1 to the latest stable version in the 70 series. I would appreciate some guidance and recommendations regarding the upgrade process.
Here are my specific questions:
What is the recommended approach to upgrading React Native when there is a significant version gap? Should I upgrade step by step or can I directly jump to the latest version in the 70 series?
Which stable version in the 70 series would you suggest for upgrading from 0.61.0? Are there any known issues or considerations I should be aware of?
Upgrading Version
I'm looking to upgrade to 0.72.0.
Any tips, insights, or personal experiences related to this upgrade would be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

## You can use [Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) Tool to upgrade your React Native version

it is a web tool to help you upgrade your React Native by using source and target version of react native
[image]

## ⚙️ How to use

### Manual

1. open https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/
2. choose `source version` and `destination version`
3. copy diff changes into your project
4. update react-native packages by seeing the compatible version with React native version

### Automatic

you can use this cli to upgrade

```
npx react-native upgrade
```

**Note:** by this command, you can get merge conflicts which you have to resolve manually

**Note:** Backup your project first before updating your app

Comment: any affiliation with the author of that youtube video? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: @starball i have no affiliation with author of youtube video, it is cofounder company of react-native who made a video of it, in react-native community everyone trusts on callstack company

Comment: @starball if you wanna remove this youtube link then i can remove and write all the procedures of using it

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) tool.

> The **Upgrade Helper** is a web tool to help you out when upgrading your apps by providing the full set of changes happening between any two versions. It also shows comments on specific files to help understanding why that change is needed.

##### 1. Select the versions

You first need to select from and to which version you wish to upgrade, by default the latest major versions are selected. After selecting you can click the button "Show me how to upgrade".

> **note**: Major updates will show an "useful content" section on the top with links to help you out when upgrading.

##### 2.Upgrade dependencies

The first file that is shown is the `package.json`, it's good to update the dependencies that are showing in there.
 For example, if `react-native` and `react` appears as changes then you can install it in your project by running yarn add or npm install:

```
yarn add react-native@{{VERSION}}
yarn add react@{{REACT_VERSION}}
```

`{{VERSION}}` and `{{REACT_VERSION}}` are the release versions showing in the difference there.

##### 3.Upgrade your project files

The new release may contain updates to other files that are generated when you run `npx react-native init`, those files are listed after the `package.json` in the Upgrade Helper page.
 If there aren't other changes then you only need to rebuild the project to continue developing.

---

In case there are changes then you can either update them manually by copying and pasting from the changes in the page or you can do it with the React Native CLI upgrade command by running:

```js
npx react-native upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

As there were changes to various core files, after trying to upgrade using the upgrade helper, I opted to create a new project with the newest version.

I merged in the development branch, keeping the core files from the new project i.e. the podfile, metro conf.

Our project only had about two dozen dependencies which also needed upgrading or changing to a more recent implementation.

I then also used the upgrade helper and read all the notes for upgrading step by step so that I didn't miss the changes it reports and checked against our project.

I tested and rectified issues as they were encountered.

I merged in the latest changes from develop.

We have successfully upgraded from 61.3 to 72.4.

I then did a PR back into develop.

I apologise if I have neglected anything - this was completed about 6 months ago.